# Stealth bombers range and visibility

Tags: civilization-5

There seems to be either a misprint or error regarding the range on the stealth bomber in the [Wiki](http://wiki.2kgames.com/civ5/index.php/Stealth_Bomber) as well as the in game info, which both state it is 20. Yet, when sitting in my city the visual range is only 6. Seems odd that it has a stated range of 20, yet I can't hit anything that far out as it is not visible.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15972/why-wont-a-stealth-bomber-fire-on-cities-anymore

Answer (score 5):

This is not an error, the range is 20 but it is limited by visibility. You have to use other units to make the targets visible, then you will be able to attack them.